# Is the suffix "-oco" an augmentative or a diminutive?

Tags: diminutivos, sufixos

Suffixes such as:

- *-inho* and *-ito* express a [diminutive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Diminutive+suffix);
- *-ão* expresses an [augmentative](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/augmentative).

What about *-oco*? The [wiktionary](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/-oco) mentions it's related to the idea of augmenting or frequency.

I thought that ***passaroco*** (related to *pássaro*) and ***bicharoco*** (related to *bicho*) were not necessarily a bigger bird or bug, respectively. There are also a few types of bacteria that have this suffix:

- [micrococo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/micrococo), "Bactéria de ínfimo tamanho";
- [monococo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/monococo), "Nome com que se designam os micrococos (coccus) que se apresentam isolados";
- [pneumococo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pneumococo), "Bactéria causadora da pneumonia";
- [meningococo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/meningococo).

However, I found that [*-coco*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/-coco) is specifically related to varieties of bacteria.

So, is the *-oco* suffix an augmentative? And are the *-coco* and *-oco* suffixes related?

Comment: Um [passaroco](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/passaroco) é um pássaro **pequeno**, mas um [bicharoco](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bicharoco) é um bicho **grande**! O Português é uma língua traiçoeira.... :)

Comment: Há mais exemplos de palavras formadas com *-oco*?

Comment: Há também _badalhoco_, _dorminhoco_ e _massaroco_.

Comment: Curioso que o Priberam diga que _bicharoco_ é um bicho grande ou asqueroso e o Aulete simplesmente asqueroso. A minha ideia é precisamente a contrária -- é um bicho não muito grande e até amigável.  Os resultados de uma pesquisa por `[lema="bicharoco"]` no CETEMPúblico vão no mesmo sentido (_O primeiro «monstro» do cinema digno desse nome era até um bicharoco simpático e amigável._)

Comment: @Artefacto Quere-me parecer que a definição do Periberam (ou da infopédia) se refere a insetos ou vermes. Mas nós usamos *bicharoro* de forma muito mais livre, usando-o também para mamíferos. E aí um bicho pode ser qualquer coisa, de rato a elefante; bicharoco deixa de significar bicho grande.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tendo de escolher entre aumentativo e dimunitivo, aumentativo será. Analisando as várias palavras sufixadas *-oco*, o valor contudo mais presente é o **pejorativo**.

Note-se que o sufixo *-coco*, que designa um tipo de bactéria, não está relacionado com o sufixo *-oco*.

Sílvia Skorge inclui *-oco* num artigo do [tomo XVII do Boletim de Filologia](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/conhecer/biblioteca-digital-camoes/lingua-1/244-244/file.html) sobre diminutivos em português. Segundo a autora dá a entender, o sufixo terá tido em fases anteriores da língua um valor de diminutivo, mas, com uma exceção (*passaroco*), tem hoje caráter pejorativo ou aumentativo:

> Também *-oco* deixou de ser produtivo no português actual. Só aparece em termos isolados dando-lhes um carácter pejorativo ou aumentativo junto à ideia de fealdade. Só num caso parece ter ainda função diminutiva: *passaroco* «pássaro pequeno».

Podem também ter um valor «humorístico-irónico»:

> No entanto, há algumas palavras que, embora não sejam diminutivas, deixam transparecer sentido mais ou menos humorístico-irónico, p. ex.: *dorminhoco* «que dorme muito, sonolento»: «...as suas lágrimas grossas ... tombaram sobre as facezitas do *dorminhoco*, despertando-o»; depois: *caroca*, derivado de *cara*, tem em Trás-os-Montes, a par de outros sentidos, o de «cabeça»; *beijoca*: «Era um temporal de beijocas num corpinho branco de neve»; *Beloca*, nome próprio.

Eu também incluiria *bicharoco* nesta categoria (se não mesmo um valor de diminutivo) e, discutivelmente, certas passagens do CETEMPúblico vão nesse sentido:

> - O simpático **bicharoco** pertence ao grupo de teatro «Os Idiotas», responsáveis pela animação na aldeia olímpica, e exibe com orgulho e distinção o seu cartão de identificação olímpica, assinado por Pasquall Maragall, o presidente do COOB.
> - No sábado, os **bicharocos** tiveram direito a desparasitação e vacinação gratuitas, para além de informação médica complementar feita por veterinários especialistas em animais de pequeno porte.
> - O primeiro «monstro» do cinema digno desse nome era até um **bicharoco** simpático e amigável

Continuando com Sílvia Skorge:

> *-oco* não parece ter valor próprio de sufixo em *pardaloca*, *pardoca* «fêmea do pardal»; *pardaloco*, porém, pode significar *passarão*, portanto é aumentativo. *Alvaroco* é «espécie de vinho em Santo Tirso», derivado da designação de cor, como também *verdelho de verde*.
>
> Aliás, *-oco* é pejorativo. *Engenhoca* é, segundo Figueiredo, expressão brasileira significando «pequeno engenho, destinado especialmente à fabricação de aguardente»; no entanto, no calão de Lisboa, pode ser também: «coisa malfeita, coisa complicada». É um «palavrão» o derivado de *badalo*: *badalhoca* «mulher suja». Outras expressões aumentativas referindo-se a algo de feio e repugnante são, p. ex.: *bicharoco*, *beiçoca*, *bichoco*, *bichoca*.

[Outras palavras com *-oco*](https://books.google.nl/books?id=_lpfAAAAMAAJ&q=%22sufixo%20-oco%22&dq=%22sufixo%20-oco%22&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&redir_esc=y) não referidas até aqui:

- Valor depreciativo: *dramalhoco*, *mijoca* (bebida ordinária)
- *empenhoca*, *lambisoca*, *maniocas* (*lavas as maniocas*)

Esta [resposta do Ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-origem-de-alvoco-nome-de-rio/33030) de Carlos Rocha a explicar a origem do topónimo *Alvoco*, refere-se ao sufixo como sendo um “diminutivo depreciativo”, dando como exemplo *passaroco* e *bicharoco*.

Answer (score 1):

The suffix **"coco"**, when it refers to bacteria means that they are spherical-shaped (**"coccus"**, plural **"cocci"**) so we have pneumococo, meningococo, gonococo, estreptococo, estafilococo, etc. (though in a scientific environment, in ptBR, we use the Latin terminology: "pneumococcus",  "meningococcus", "gonococcus", "streptococcus" and "stafilococcus") All of them have the suffix "coccus" which means, as I said before, spherical-shaped. This has nothing to do with "passaroco" or "bicharoco".  To be honest, I doubt these words are ever used in standard ptBR. Surely, not where I come from.

Answer (score -1):

About the name of the bacteria, coconut refers only their shape

No caso do nome das bactérias é relativo à forma delas ser oval ou arredondada como um coco.

Bacteria in round or oval shape are known as coconut.

No caso dos passaroco no Brasil só se usa passarinho. Bicharoco nunca ouvi.
In the case of Passoroco in Brazil only uses Passarinho. Bicharoco never heard about.

inho is not only used for diminutive, to reduce something size or shape. You can even indicate the opposite, something of greater intensity or size.

inho não é usado apenas para diminutivos no sentido de reduzir algo de tamanho ou forma. Pode inclusive indicar o contrário, algo de maior intensidade ou tamanho.

menininho = menino pequeno (small boy)

fininho = bem fino ,  muito fino (very thin)

rapidinho = bem rápido, muito rápido (very fast)

você está bem grandinho (you grew considerably) = mais alto, maior (taller, bigger)

Comment: Bem vindo ao PortugueseLanguageSE! Essa resposta precisa ser melhorada. Quando a pergunta for feita em inglês e somente em inglês, é interessante respondê-la em inglês ou em inglês E em português. Sua resposta tem apenas um trecho em inglês que está desconexo do restante da resposta.

Comment: Entendido. Fiz algumas mudanças.